# Dialogflow intents with and without question

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have created bot that will contact with dialogflow and will get an answer. My problem is, let's say someone entered text `Hi bot` then my bot will return back `hello Name`. And after that user will ask `how are you?` bot says `i am fine thanks and you?`. But it is problem when user enters like `Hi. how are you?`. My question is: is it possible to handle it with one intents? or I must create different intents? I mean one for `hi, hello...` another one for `how are you...` and another one for `Hi. How are you?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to id. Just created entities something like `question` with values `how are you, how r u, how are u ...` and used it in intents as parameter. In response added answers like `hello, hi` and `hello. i am fine thanks and you? Hi, i am ok. ...` Used created parameters at then end of response like:

```
1) hello. i am fine thanks and you? & $question &
2) Hi, i am ok. & $question &
3) Hello
4) Hi
```

So if there is something like `Hello. How are you?` then it will look to 1 and 2 response only. If it is just `Hello or hi` then it will look to 3 and 4.

in my code i have just deleted `& $question &`.

Answer (score 1):

Always remember that **Intents represent what the user is saying - not how you're responding**. You should design the conversational bot according to that.

In your case, I think, `hi. how are you` should be part of same intent which will be have training phrase `how are you` and your bot should respond `i am fine thanks and you?`. Because that's how we generally converse.
So you don't need another intent.

Comment: Yes exactly, in my mother language when we are saying ```hi.how are you?``` we answer ```hi. i am fine thanks.``` not ```i am fine thanks.```. But i found solution. I have added value to response like ```&$value&``` and in my code i am deleting it. so bot will answer correct.

Comment: @MRustamzade you should put that as answer so that it helps other having same problem. :)