# Possibility of dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

im new on dialogflow

[Dialogflow intents with and without question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54783812/dialogflow-intents-with-and-without-question)
i already read this question, but its not answer my question.

so my requirement is like this

1. I have 100 paragraphs
2. I want to put 100 paragraphs to database
3. when the user asks something, the engine will automatically answer by looking for answers in the 100 paragraphs earlier

example:

1. I have 100 paragraphs about `PHP programming learning materials`
2. I input all the `learning materials` into the database
3. I asked `how to replace the string`? then the engine will answer by looking for answers in those 100 paragraphs

so my requirement is engine that without `training phrases`, the answers can be automatically searched in those `100 paragraphs`.

is this possible in dialogflow?

Comment: Hi @Diky Ridhlo, for your requirement, you can create a Spanner instance wher you can store data and create a Cloud Function to query the database. For more details you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/tutorials/deploy/database). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Isn't Spanner overkill? @ShipraSarkar

Comment: Dialogflow won't work this way, it maps an intent to a response. So if you have a knowledge base about PHP Programming, you would need to map each type off question into "intents" by adding training phrases and this would need to be robust. Then once an intent is triggered, you can pass it to wherever your codebase is running, and ask it to query your database. I don't think Spanner is a good idea for storing answers.

Comment: So for example, if you have an intent for how to replace the string, you would need to create  an intent for that, map it to a specific record/s in your database. However, as you mentioned you don't want to train your bot, which is quite confusing, but from what I understand, Dialogflow isn't the right solution for this. I would suggest something like ElasticSearch.

Comment: Dialogflow has a Knowledge Base feature, but speaking from personal experience, its not good and has not reached GA for quite some time. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/knowledge-connectors It can automate the set up of intent to a specific intent for you, assuming your data in a supported format. You are welcome to try it out and see how it works for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i got it. i think i should change to OpenAI. its possible on OpenAI